# How to remove a class on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prueba"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.prueba {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS (Edited):**

```
var main = function() {
    $('.prueba').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('.prueba');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

It (still) doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your selector doesn't know you're selecting a CSS class. For that you must input 'prueba' with a dot, like .prueba. If it was an ID, so that would be #prueba and so on.

Comment: `$('.prueba').removeClass('prueba');` Add dot to first prueba and remove from the second one. ;)

Comment: `$('prueba')` means "select all elements with tag type `prueba` and would only match `<prueba attr="value"></prueba>`. Use `$('.prueba')` to select a class or `$('#prueba')` to select an ID - just like CSS

Comment: your selector is wrong.  It should be:

 `$('.prueba').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('prueba');
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select class, you should preface class name with a dot:

```
$('.prueba')
```

[JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) you may want to review.